# Twitter bootstrap modal undo the changes made by modal submit

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog

I have a jsp form with start date and end date as input fields.
I also have a button on the jsp thats opens a twitter bootstrap modal with another form having search period as a field.

Submitting search period should close the modal and update the start date in jsp.

but right now the modal I have submits the search period and does also updates the start date but if you click anywhere on the form undo the changes on start period.

can anyone help me on this:
Here is my modal:

```
 <div id="myModal" class="modal hide fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
        <h4 id="myModalLabel">IpPortMac Preferences</h4>
    </div>
    <form:form class="form-horizontal" modelAttribute="ipPortMacPref" id="updatePreferencesForm">

    <div class="modal-body">
            <div class="control-group">
                <form:label class="control-label" path="searchPeriod">Default Search Period:  </form:label>
                <div class="controls">
                    <div class="input-append" id="searchPeriod">
                        <form:input path='searchPeriod' name='searchPeriod' id="sPeriod"/>
                    </div>
                    <div class="input-append">Days</div>
                </div>
            </div>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
        <button class="btn" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">Close</button>
        <button class="btn btn-primary" name="submit" data-toggle="model" type="submit" value="submit">Save changes</button>
    </div>
    </form:form>

</div>
```